# How display custom error message above a model field in Django admin when a JSONSchemaValidationError occured?

Tags: django, django-models, jsonschema, json-schema-validator, django-errors

I'm using JSONSchema validation but when an exception occurred it throw a validation error that will display the Validation Error message on a separate page. But I want to display an error message on the admin page next to that field displaying why the value is not saved.

[image]

```
class Product(models.Model):
        new_tags = models.JSONField(null=True, default=None, blank=True, help_text="Tag must be a valid JSON tag. Tag should be in the form of &ltTagName_tag&gt.")
.
.
.
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Product, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        # If new_tags is not empty, validate with JSONSchema
        if self.new_tags is not None:
            try:
                validate(
                    instance=self.new_tags,
                    schema=get_tags_json_schema(),
                )
            except JSONSchemaValidationError:
                raise ValidationError(
                    {'new_tags': "Error trying to insert a tag: the JSON is invalid"}
                )
```

Comment: can you add code too

Comment: hi @daneilJames, I added code too.

Comment: please add your model too once

Comment: can you do this same in your models.py rather than on admin.py